# Is there a trick to embed Report Charts inside a custom Lightning Component (or anyhow so that they are available in the mobile app)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, report-chart, flexipages

In LEX I have embedded report charts in a tab on a flexipage like that:

[image]

I need to expose the charts also in the mobile app.

I know that it's possible to embed up to 2 charts on the page-layout and this is NOT what I'm looking for.

Is there (except of the layout-way) any **other** way to add report chats into a custom LC or get them shown using a quick action or anyhow so that they get exposed in the mobile app.